Why b2sum verifier not working from this powershell script?
I am having errors while verifying ISO b2sum as it is showing these errors:
 GoniFahad    ISO   22.4.1     0ms⠀   .\VerifyISO.ps1 -isoFilePath .\archlinux-2024.07.01-x86_64.iso                                     pwsh  17:02:36 
Select verification method (1: .sig, 2: b2sums.txt, 3: sha256sums.txt, e.g., 1,2 or 1,3):: 2
Enter the path to the b2sums.txt file: b2sums.txt
wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: fetch failed
falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation
D:\ARCH\ISO\node_modules\blake2.wasm\src\blake2.js:8
if(p){var t,u;a.read=function(b,c){t||(t=require("fs"));u||(u=require("path"));b=u.normalize(b);b=t.readFileSync(b);return c?b:b.toString()};a.readBinary=function(b){b=a.read(b,!0);b.buffer||(b=new Uint8Array(b));assert(b.buffer);return b};1<process.argv.length&&(a.thisProgram=process.argv[1].replace(/\\/g,"/"));a.arguments=process.argv.slice(2);process.on("uncaughtException",function(b){if(!(b instanceof v))throw b;});process.on("unhandledRejection",function(){process.exit(1)});a.inspect=function(){return"[Emscripten Module object]"}}else if(q)"undefined"!=
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\ARCH\ISO\.archlinux-2024.07.01-x86_64.iso'
Emitted 'error' event on ReadStream instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:170:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'D:\\ARCH\\ISO\\.archlinux-2024.07.01-x86_64.iso'
}

Node.js v22.4.1
Write-Error: D:\ARCH\ISO\VerifyISO.ps1:130
Line |
 130 |  …             Verify-With-B2Sums -isoFilePath $isoFilePath -b2sumsFileP …
     |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | BLAKE2 verification failed.

Am I missing something here since this is the said directory involved...

 GoniFahad    ISO   22.4.1     9.232s⠀   ls                                                                                                                  
    Directory: D:\ARCH\ISO

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----           7/15/2024  4:45 PM                node_modules
-a---            7/2/2024 12:10 AM     1173389312 archlinux-2024.07.01-x86_64.iso
-a---           7/15/2024  7:22 AM            141 archlinux-2024.07.01-x86_64.iso.sig
-a---           7/15/2024  7:24 AM            656 b2sums.txt
-a---           7/15/2024  4:12 PM       35521800 gpg4win-4.3.1.exe
-a---           7/15/2024  4:46 PM            767 package-lock.json
-a---           7/15/2024  4:45 PM             81 package.json
-a---           7/15/2024  7:24 AM            400 sha256sums.txt
-a---           7/15/2024  4:59 PM           5407 VerifyISO.ps1
-a---           7/15/2024  7:53 AM      109700144 VirtualBox-7.0.18-162988-Win.exe

The verifier script that I've used is this:
param (
    [string]$isoFilePath
)

function Import-Public-Key {
    param (
        [string]$publicKeyPath
    )
    gpg --import $publicKeyPath
}

function Verify-With-Sig {
    param (
        [string]$isoFilePath,
        [string]$sigFilePath
    )
    if (!(Get-Command gpg -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        Write-Error "GPG is not installed. Please install it from https://gnupg.org/download/index.html"
        return
    }
    gpg --verify $sigFilePath $isoFilePath
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) {
        Write-Output "Verification with .sig file succeeded."
    } else {
        Write-Error "Verification with .sig file failed. If the error is 'No public key', please import the public key."
    }
}

function Verify-With-B2Sums {
    param (
        [string]$isoFilePath,
        [string]$b2sumsFilePath
    )
    if (!(Get-Command node -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        Write-Error "Node.js is not installed. Please install it from https://nodejs.org/"
        return
    }
    if (!(Get-Command npm -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        Write-Error "NPM is not installed. Please ensure NPM is installed with Node.js."
        return
    }
    $blake2Installed = npm list -g | Select-String -Pattern "blake2.wasm"
    if (-not $blake2Installed) {
        Write-Output "Installing blake2.wasm npm package..."
        npm install -g blake2.wasm
        if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
            Write-Error "Failed to install blake2.wasm. Please ensure npm is installed and try again."
            return
        }
    }

    $expectedHash = (Get-Content $b2sumsFilePath).Trim() -replace "  .*", ""
    $hash = & node -e "
    const fs = require('fs');
    const blake2 = require('blake2.wasm');
    blake2.ready(() => {
        const inputFile = '$isoFilePath';
        const readStream = fs.createReadStream(inputFile);
        const hash = new blake2.Blake2b(64);
        readStream.on('data', chunk => hash.update(chunk));
        readStream.on('end', () => {
            const result = hash.final();
            console.log(Buffer.from(result).toString('hex'));
        });
    });
    " | Out-String
    $hash = $hash.Trim()

    if ($hash -eq $expectedHash) {
        Write-Output "BLAKE2 verification succeeded."
    } else {
        Write-Error "BLAKE2 verification failed."
    }
}

function Verify-With-Sha256Sums {
    param (
        [string]$isoFilePath,
        [string]$sha256sumsFilePath
    )
    $hash = Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 $isoFilePath
    $hashString = $hash.Hash.ToLower()
    $expectedHash = Get-Content $sha256sumsFilePath | Select-String -Pattern $hashString

    if ($expectedHash) {
        Write-Output "SHA-256 verification succeeded."
    } else {
        Write-Error "SHA-256 verification failed."
    }
}

function Main {
    param (
        [string]$isoFilePath
    )

    if (!(Test-Path $isoFilePath)) {
        Write-Error "ISO file not found: $isoFilePath"
        return
    }

    $verificationMethod = Read-Host "Select verification method (1: .sig, 2: b2sums.txt, 3: sha256sums.txt, e.g., 1,2 or 1,3):"

    $methods = $verificationMethod -split ","
    foreach ($method in $methods) {
        switch ($method.Trim()) {
            "1" {
                $sigFilePath = Read-Host "Enter the path to the .sig file"
                if (Test-Path $sigFilePath) {
                    Verify-With-Sig -isoFilePath $isoFilePath -sigFilePath $sigFilePath
                    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
                        $importKey = Read-Host "Verification failed. Do you want to import a public key? (yes/no)"
                        if ($importKey -eq "yes") {
                            $publicKeyPath = Read-Host "Enter the path to the public key file"
                            if (Test-Path $publicKeyPath) {
                                Import-Public-Key -publicKeyPath $publicKeyPath
                                Verify-With-Sig -isoFilePath $isoFilePath -sigFilePath $sigFilePath
                            } else {
                                Write-Error "Public key file not found: $publicKeyPath"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Write-Error "Signature file not found: $sigFilePath"
                }
            }
            "2" {
                $b2sumsFilePath = Read-Host "Enter the path to the b2sums.txt file"
                if (Test-Path $b2sumsFilePath) {
                    Verify-With-B2Sums -isoFilePath $isoFilePath -b2sumsFilePath $b2sumsFilePath
                } else {
                    Write-Error "b2sums file not found: $b2sumsFilePath"
                }
            }
            "3" {
                $sha256sumsFilePath = Read-Host "Enter the path to the sha256sums.txt file"
                if (Test-Path $sha256sumsFilePath) {
                    Verify-With-Sha256Sums -isoFilePath $isoFilePath -sha256sumsFilePath $sha256sumsFilePath
                } else {
                    Write-Error "sha256sums file not found: $sha256sumsFilePath"
                }
            }
            default {
                Write-Error "Invalid verification method selected: $method"
            }
        }
    }
}

Main -isoFilePath $isoFilePath


You write 'D:\ARCH\ISO\.archlinux-2024.07.01-x86_64.iso' but the file that exists is 'D:\ARCH\ISO\archlinux-2024.07.01-x86_64.iso' (you added a '.') can't see how you call the function, but if you call a function and use a file that doesn't exist, its not gonna work.

@LPChip $isoFilePath does this look like it's taking 'D:\ARCH\ISO\.archlinux-2024.07.01-x86_64.iso'... I don't understand.

Find out how you define the $isoFilePath, and give it the path of that iso. Your problem is there. Somewhere it adds a .
